# SVG stroke-dashoffset not working on safari

Tags: css, svg, safari

Stroke-dashoffset is not working on safari even if I add -webkit- prefix. please help me. Thanks!....

Here is my sample code....

```
#path1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2s ease;
  animation: dash 2s ease;
  display:inline-block;
}
.path2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2s ease;
  animation: dash 2s ease;
  display:inline-block;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
  stroke-dashoffset: -500;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
  stroke-dashoffset: -500;
  }
}
```

Comment: Help us to help you. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 12):

Safari does not support negative stroke-dashoffset......

Answer (score 7):

It’s not that ["Safari doesn't support negative `stroke-dashoffset"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39127818/2180570), per the accepted answer. Safari is actually following the spec. Chrome, Firefox, etc are breaking with the spec, possibly because they realized the spec was poorly defined.

Here is the [SVG spec's definition of `stroke-dashoffset`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/painting.html#StrokeDashoffsetProperty). Some things to note:

1. Positive `stroke-dashoffset` values do not march the dash line forward, from the start of the path to the end of the path: they move it backwards. This is because it's defined as "the distance into the dash pattern where the path starts", rather than "how far along the path the pattern starts" as you would think.
2. Negative `stroke-dashoffset` values do not march the dash line backward, exactly. That is, crossing over from > 0 to < 0 does not always continue the smooth march of dashes. The true behavior is peculiar✝ and appears unpredictable on the surface.

In short, `dashoffset` works nothing like you'd expect. And you should probably avoid negative values if at all possible to avoid confusion.

**Solution**

The common way to get around this is to just remove the negative sign and reverse the animation, which usually (possibly always?) should result in the desired effect:

```
#path {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  animation: dash 2s ease reverse;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  }
}
```

**Discussion✝**

I believe the confusion ultimately stems from ambiguity in this line in the spec:

```
where s is the sum of the dash array values.
```

Does "dash array values" mean the values provided by the user in the attribute? Or does it refer to the array of values after [being processed](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/painting.html#StrokeDashing), with odd-length arrays being repeated to yield even-length arrays (eg `stroke-dasharray="10"` becomes `stroke-dasharray="10 10"`). Safari seems to interpret it as the former, Chrome and Firefox the latter.

For example, with `stroke-dasharray="10"`, the spec says `stroke-dashoffset="-1"` will look the same as `stroke-dashoffset="9"` per the spec. But in Chrome and Firefox, it will look the same as `stroke-dashoffset="19"`. However, if you set `stroke-dasharray="10 10"`, it seems to behave as you would hope.

**Clarifying the spec**

Here's an issue I created on the spec regarding negative dash offsets:
https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/795

If you found this frustrating, give the issue some comments or 's and maybe they'll fix it.

Comment: The SVG 1.1 spec did not contain this text. If you feel things can be improved, take it up with w3c and get the spec changed further. If Chrome and Firefox agree, it's probably easiest to get Safari to fix their implementation.

Answer (score 3):

As above, negative values don‘t work for stroke-dashoffset. If you shift your values to positive numbers this should work (you’ll need to shift your initial value too):

```
.path2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1500;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the desired result by just animating the `stroke-dashoffset` to the doubled value of `stroke-dasharray`

Step one:
[image]

Step two:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with negative `stroke-dashoffet`. Hence, I used positive value instead and flipped the SVG.

In my particular case, I resolved it by flipping the SVG by using `transform:scaleX(-1)`.

Depending on your requirement, flipping the SVG might work.

Answer (score 0):

**SVG Animate tag seems to work without css**

```html
  <path stroke-dasharray="500" other attr>
    <animate 
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" 
      from="-500" 
      to="500"
      dur="3s" // duration
      begin="2s" // delay
      fill="freeze"/>
  </path>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ensure, your **snippets are rendering a visible result.** Your example is missing a parent `<svg>` element. Besides, you're right stroke related svg attributes like `stroke-offset` or `stroke-dasharray` can also be defined or animated via native SMIL animation or svg attributes.